# ngx-cookieconsent : Cannot find name 'NgcInitializeEvent' and 'NgcStatusChangeEvent'

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-cli, banner

I would like to use ngx-cookie consent package in my angular 4 application(built with angular cli) . I do not have a systemjs file. Hence except that part , I followed each step as in the documentation ( https://tinesoft.github.io/ngx-cookieconsent/doc/index.html).
 I am having 4 error messages

1. two errors with following message

   ```
   //Cannot read property 'initialise' of undefined at 
   //NgcCookieConsentService.init (cookieconsent.service.js:53)
   //at new NgcCookieConsentService (cookieconsent.service.js:23)
   //at _createClass (core.es5.js:9532)
   //at createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9500)
   //at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:948 5) 
   //at NgModuleRef.get (core.es5.js:10577)
   //at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11080)
   //at createClass (core.es5.js:10933)
   //at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10764)
   //at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12212)
   ```

   2. Cannot find name 'NgcInitializeEvent'.
      Cannot find name 'NgcStatusChangeEvent'.

Please help.

Comment: have you done the `@NgModule` `imports: [NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig), ...],  ` part?

Comment: yes, I have done it. also i have another module- (app-routing-module.ts), I have included it there as well without the parameter cookieConfig.

Comment: Turns out the first error  was because of dependancies not installed properly (running " del -rf node_modules" command worked - https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent/issues/2). I still have the second issue though! Due to which the cookie appears everytime the page is opened .

Answer (score 8):

I'm the author of [ngx-cookieconsent](https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent/).
I have already answered the issues on the project's issues tracker, but for future googlers, here they are:

1. 'NgcInitializeEvent' and 'NgcStatusChangeEvent' not found

You need to import them, if you want to use these events in your code:

```
import { NgcInitializeEvent, NgcStatusChangeEvent } from 'ngx-cookieconsent';
```

2. Cookie status not persisted

your need to set `'cookie.domain'` parameter of configuration object (even in localhost), for cookies to be set properly:

```
import {NgcCookieConsentModule, NgcCookieConsentConfig} from 'ngx-cookieconsent';

const cookieConfig:NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: 'localhost' // or 'your.domain.com' // it is mandatory to set a domain (even in localhost), for cookies to work properly
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Note:** if you are using Angular CLI for your consuming app, you can take advantage of [environments](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments) to control the domain based on your running environment:

**environments/environment.ts:** (dev)

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  cookieDomain: 'localhost' // -<< must be 'localhost'
};
```

**environments/environment.prod.ts:** (prod)

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  cookieDomain: 'your.domain.com' // -<< must be the domain of deployed app
};
```

and use it as such:

```
import {NgcCookieConsentModule, NgcCookieConsentConfig} from 'ngx-cookieconsent';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

const cookieConfig:NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: environment.cookieDomain // -<< domain will change base on your running env
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgcCookieConsentModule.forRoot(cookieConfig), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: how to use cookie consent for Angular 5?

Comment: I`m just following up with this :) I get an error when trying to run my app... the error is:

```An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ../node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.js does not exist.``` Any idea why this error is here? I have that file in the nodes modules..

Comment: Seems you have to install "cookieconsent" as well from npm/yarn

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It solved by adding the `min.js` and `min.css` to `angular.json` file.
See: https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent